# How old does Peter Parker get?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, spider-man

In some incarnations, we see Peter Parker as a high school student. In other incarnations we see him as a college student at Empire State University. And in yet other incarnations we see Peter as a young adult working for the Daily Bugle.

**How old does Peter Parker get in any of the Marvel universes?**  Note that I am including the Marvel tag to include comics and television in addition to the movies.

Comment: Rebooting isn't dependent on his age; are you asking what age he was in each of the recent 3 movie universes?

Comment: There are A LOT of Marvel universes, many with Peter Parkers. You might want to narrow it down to at least the primary comics universes. I am pretty sure that there are What-Ifs with Peter living to any number of ripe old ages.

Comment: @Politank I am not including brief premonitions of future old age. I am asking how old he gets on a day to day basis. Not sure what words concisely state that obvious assumption, so I opted for a brief OP.

Comment: That's not what I am referring to. Marvel Comics has a vast multiverse with many incarnations of its primary characters.

Comment: @Politank-Z Google also has a vast database of meta-analyses of such things. I am sure that the truth is out there.

Comment: Imagine if he could live as long as a spider.

Comment: Exactly my first thought...male spiders have an even shorter lifespan as female spiders. However, the question specifically refers to the Marvel universes (plural). Not to anything real-life-ish. Plus, in real life, the square–cube law would be a *serious* issue for Peter Parker...

Comment: @CodeMed To facilitate answers to both sides of your question (the Main comic continuity, and TV and films) I made 2 answers; one dealing with the TV and a film version, and one dissecting the comics, sticking mostly to Peter's 616 version. Originally, it was intended as a single answer, but because the information went in two different directions, I thought it best to separate. Also, both ran a bit long. It then occurred to me I may have interpreted the query wrong: are you asking Peter's _maximum portrayed_ age, _how_  he ages relative to real time, or his _average age_ across various media?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The oldest version of Peter Parker that we see is probably the one in ***Spider-Man: Reign***. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Reign) describes him as "late 60s, early 70s", which seems about right:

[image]

In this version, Peter Parker has long since retired from his life as Spider-Man and lives alone as a florist in a dystopian future city, because

> he accidentally killed Mary Jane with his radioactive bodily fluids.

It takes place in the "[Earth-70237](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-70237)" timeline.

Comment: Why does he mention "his wife" if he's living alone? Or is the posted image a flashback to when he wasn't single in the past?

Comment: I'm assuming he didn't bleed on her?

Comment: @Flater It's been a while since I read it, but iirc he was going to say something like "she died and was making most of our income".

Comment: @ArthurDent I wish I was making this up  https://www.wired.com/2007/02/spidermans_radi/

Comment: @MiloP: Makes sense. Although, that should either mean that she died _recently_ (and they never had sex until they were both senior citizens), or old Peter must be mentioning something from a long past that shouldn't really apply to his current living situation anymore.

Answer (score 2):

**Specific Context Answer:** Currently, the main Comic Book continuity Earth 616 Peter Parker is a young adult; as of this writing (2020), he is portrayed as *no older* than 31, more than likely closer to 28. This is just an estimation: giving a canonical age will be difficult, due to the nature of comics, and a sliding time scale.

To be fair, "aging" in comics is subjective; not only are there various versions/universes of the *Same* character, but ret-cons and reboots often occur, starting the same story "over again" fresh with the same *version,* just in a different decade. More than that, though aging *is* addressed in comics, its **rarely**  consistent, so in general, most heroes will be around for literal *Decades,* but only age *a decade* at most.

The same is true in many works of fiction, especially when "Reboots" are done for the purpose of introducing a *new* audience to a character for that newer generation.

**NOTE:** The use of Sliding Time Scales/Time Lines to keep things/characters "current" are *very* common in fiction, and **especially** so in comic books.

The simple goal of keeping people in touch with characters they know means that, for the most part, characters rarely change too much. However, as "real world time" marches on, stories for these characters have to be consequently *updated.* This is the media essentially "keeping with the changing times", in terms of tastes, thematic relevance, aesthetics/looks and registering with the audience so that the book/show/character continues to sell. While there *are* some characters that age according to normal chronological time, and their styles and stories reflect this, it's rare; Savage Dragon is one such character, and Dr. Who is another....though "The Doctor" is something of a special case, as he *acknolwedges* that there are "several time-uneccumbered versions" of himself with different ages, faces, personalities, characters and looks.

So what usually happens is that a specific time period (most often reflected by a decade) of a story becomes "fluid"; canon adventures and occurances still happen to the characters and months or years will pass in between events, but the actual *date* of when a given event happens shifts, usually coming in later and later in the personal history as the "event date itself" is moved forward or updated. This constant slipping forward will consequently keep the *character* at relatively the same age, while simultaneously elongating/updating the *story's* life, even as more in-story "events" are piled on to its continuity.

**Example:** You know how *The Simpsons* have been a series for **over 30 years,** but its the *same exact story and characters* ....even though **nobody ever ages?!** It's exactly like that; the show's continuity "slides forth", so that the characters always *remain the same age,* even as more and more events happen. However, to justify this seeming "aglessness", continuous ret-cons will occur that "tweak" the history just a little, so that the Simpsons all being their current ages makes sense. The caveat is this history-tweaking **has** to work without altering certain canon happenings, effecting major story beats (Sideshow Bob hating Bart, for example) *or* changing current realities.

For a Simpsons-specific example...nobody can deny that Bart *exists,* right? Well, for *that* to happen, Homer and Marge *have* to meet and fall in love; that's just an immutable part of Simpsons canon. The *canon* is written in stone; at some interval in time, 10 years before the character *we* know as Bart is "here" in the "now," his parents **have** to concieve him. However, whether that's the 1980s, the 1990s, the 2000s or later depends; Bart will *always* be 10, most likely, but if he's 10 in the 2000s, that means even though, in a meta sense, the actual show *started in the 80s,* the "chronological canon" would mean he was actually "born" only 10 years before the *current* decade he is in.

In show, this means that chronological events all *happened,* (Homer meeting Marge, them falling love, Marge getting pregnant, Homer starting work at the Power Plant, etc) but they all will then seemed to have "happened" at *ever later* decades. This is *exactly* why there are no less than **3** stories of how Homer and Marge got together in their "Youth" in high school... once in the 70s, once in the 80s, and once in the late 90s. Essentially, their personal history didn't "rewrite itself"...it just "slipped forward" a bit, so that everything happened, just a a later date, and thus their current ages make sense.

This is the effect that makes judging Peter Parker's current *comic book* age so damned difficult. I've been a Spider-fan since childhood, and my first deep association with him was the early 1980s cartoon; in this series, Peter was a 19-21 year old college student. By that account, Spider-man has been a "young adult" for *at least* 30+ years.

And Spider-man, as a character, had already been around for more than 20 years by that point; if he was to age *naturally* from the time he was introduced in the comics (1960s) Peter would *actually* be **more than 60 years old by now.**

Not exactly the prime age for a "kid proxy" or "Relatable" hero most kids are going to follow or emulate (accept maybe *Super Gran.*)

So to focus this answer a bit more, it would come across as such:
"This is Peter's cannon age in the CURRENT comics"... which again, puts him at late 20s to *early* 30s, at most.

Oddly enough, there **is** sufficient *evidence* for this age estimation, if we follow Peter's canon timeline, even accounting for ret-cons and sliding. Mind you, we're not speaking of the comic book "Chronology" here....as in the linier years of when the books were published.... but the meta "canon chronology"... the *verified* events that Peter *himself* has made reference to as "actually having happened to him" in his personal life which mark or influenced his existence.

The best way we can do *that*  isn't by accounting for his *comic* events (which could be seen to be placed on a sliding time line) but by the **interactions/Hall mark life events** that have occurred over the characters 60 year history, and which have essentially *influenced* his canon at certain ages, and thus **cannot** be denied. This way we can mark establish "points" , guess his age based on the *amount* of accumulated events at a givem time (more happenings would, of course, mean more time has passed), and then "best gues-timate" how much time passed until the next "big event/person" Peter encounters.

### Spiderman himself has, on occasion, referenced that he has been Spiderman for a number of years

Again, this can vary from work to work, and given interpretations. Put that alongside "alternate universes" and the matter gets even more complex (the *Ultimates* Marvel 1610 universe' Peter Parker, for example, is roughly **a full ten years younger** than our "main" 616 Universe incarnation.) Our version, however, has indicated he's a grown adult with a long-standing crime fighting career:

[image]

This panel as taken from Marvels *Avengers: Civil War* storyline, which occurred back in 2006-2007. Spider-man publicly revealed his identity, to show his solidarity with Tony Stark's "Pro registration" stance. It should be noted that, at this point in Peter's history, he had been married to Mary Jane for years and they had lost their first child. Considering that she was **not** his first long-term adult relationship by a *long shot* (more on that later) Peter's in-story age at this point would likely be mid-to-late 20s. It is assumed that, in story currently, he hasn't aged *much* from this point and the whole "Civil War" debackle occurred only a few years before....

### Relationship changes

One of the best "base-line" examples I can give here would probably be Peter's friendship with Eugene "Flash" Thompson. This is because Flash has been a staple in Peter's life since they were both teenagers, and even through University. As such, they are both the same age, and we can account for how "comic time" in years have affected both.

Flash started out as the *bully* Peter had to put up with in High School (before Pete humiliated him with a display of Spider Power at some point in most stories, or Flash showed a little decency to the guy after Peter's Uncle Ben was murdered). They had an enmity through their teen years, and then grew into a sort of "rivalry" for the affections of different ladies. The two wouldn't become actual close  *friends* until their later university years, which was young adulthood:

[image]

This actual panel is from an *Amazing Spider Man* comic made in the 1970s. By this point, if he was aging according to "real time", Peter *should* be in his late 20s at *least.* However, it's indicated in-story that both men are still just in their early 20s. Flash, who is the same age as Pete, says he was in the Army for a while; considering he was *with* Peter at ESU for a bit right out of High school (18-19), and the earliest he could have enlisted was age 18, if he did perhaps a 2 year stint, this could put them both... at oldest... 21-22.

Speaking of "various ladies".... another marker of his "young adult" age was that Peter was having various girlfriends at this point. And not just a casual date or "one college sweetheart";  though he's more or less monogamous when attached, Peter Parker dated **quite a bit** in college, spending a lot of time with a *several* distinct women...

[image]

Keep in mind: Dude was *Still in University* on his first 4-yer degree when *these*  ladies shown above were in the mix! And this isn't even *half* his total romantic history!

That brings us to both a major significant marker, and a reason why most media outside of canon comics try to keep Peter young, or like to "de-age" him...

### "Adult" Relationships can Mature a character in fiction

This can be especially true in comics. Even with a sliding time scale, it can be a difficult balance for writer's to try to keep a character relatable for older fans, while *also* making the same character enticing for *newer* readers. As audiences age, many want the heroes they identify with to "Grow up with them", and thus reflect changing tastes from candy and video games to dating and romance. One of Spider-Man's most *defining* romances, as well as important relationships in comics over all, was his long-time love affair with his first  **major** girlfriend, Gwen Stacy.

Stacy was a central character, long term relationship, a genuine sweetheart, and balancing element in Peter's life for several years while he was in college. She was introduced in 1965, and remained his most central love interest for 8 years; at one point, Peter was going to propose to her. This would have changed the overall *Spider Man* dynamic and tone of the book; istead of a "care free" and "young" super dude, Peter would likely be portrayed as a more "grown up" hero dealing with marriage and other such issues *on top* of toppling super criminals.

Yet all this would come to an abrupt end when, for better or worse, Gwen was *killed off* (basically, FOR GOOD!) back in 1973.

[image]

Canonically, Gwen's death has been something that haunts Peter to **this very day,** even through his marriage with Mary Jane; not only did it change the course of *his life,* from altering priorities and not being a husband earlier, but it was **the first time EVER** an earnest hero had failed to save his loved one from doom. In a meta sense, it made comics more mature and dealt with a proper "adult" theme; many say it signaled the end of the "Silver Age" of comics.

In a continuity sense, this was a loss Peter had to suffer as an early 20-something which he never really came back from. It also defined him because it happened at that age, when Pete was still relatively young; *everything else* in is life afterwards took an adult turn, but few things amounted to such a grievous and personal loss.

This is another reason modern non canon comics and other media interpretations just **don't** let Peter age:

**1.** This is kinda "heavy stuff" for a *kids' show,* and wouldn't be easy to tackle. This is why many of the Spider Man cartoon series, most of which came *after*  this event, have basically *never touched it* .

**2.** Given that this young college couple was contemplating marriage and a life together, the loss was especially potent. A teenage Peter wouldn't likely yet *have* **that depth** of a relationship with Gwen, so the death couldn't resonant the same.

**3.** If any of the shows were to age Peter up, they would eventually **have** to tell this story; just like Uncle Ben's passing, it's very *central* to Spider Man canon.

**Note:** To be fair, the 1994 animated series did a *version* of this, but with significant changes; Peter *was* an adult, but instead of Gwen, it was the better known love interest of Mary Jane. And she didn't die, but "disappeared" through a dimensional hole.

Gwen's death was something that helped defined who Peter is as a person for *years* after; this is not something that comes with youth, but only with experience. Even late into adulthood, and being happily married to a good woman he loves dearly, he has struggled coming to terms with it, both as a failure as a hero/protector, and as a personal tragedy. Comics into the 2000s and beyond *still* show Peter "trying to make sense" of this loss and grieving for Gwen, with the man himself saying "it's been years" since it happened...

[image]

The problem of addressing this key story element is solved by one of two ways; either

1. keeping Peter young, so that he doesn't *come* to the tragedy yet, or
2. side-stepping it *entirely* by only following canon "loosely".

Most modern media does a combination of these approaches. And since TV and movies tend to be more widely seen than the comic book source material, this is yet another reason *why* Peter tends to perennially remain more "Peter Pan" than canon "Peter Parker".

### Adults can have A LOT of relationships

And Peter is NO exception! Matter of fact.... he's an *UBER example!*

Just to lighten things up after that whole "Gwen Stacy" section, we should take a look at the *other* defining relationships (and a few casual ones) in adult-Peter Parker's life. And for a guy who started off as a *total geek and science nerd* who was ignored by girls mostly and couldn't get a date to save his life in high school... **he certainly made up for it** in University and Post Grad years!

By this, I mean that,  while he is often portrayed as a bit of a wallflower as a teen, *adult* Peter Parker rivals only DC's *Dick Grayson* for the title of "Teen Hero-Turned-Chick Magnet".... and that is **saying** something!

Mind you, while "cooler", slightly older heroes like Dick's mentor Batman and Pete's own mentor/buddy Tony Stark likely have better overall "numbers", make no mistake; just like his dynamic duo DC counterpart, even after Gwen's passing, Peter Parker **definitely** gets *laid* ....

[image]

Like ... **a LOT!**

[image]

As in, **Even if he *doesn't* bed them, Guy still *somehow* catches Female interest he doesn't even *know* about and get's women WAY out of his league WANTING to bed him** a *lot* .....
[image]
[image]

As in **"DAMN, dude, just FORM YOUR OWN HAREM already!"** kinda thing!

[image]

Now----- all jokes aside------ the real significance of these adult liaisons to this specific question is this:

**1.** *All* of them are *canon*

**2.** *Most* of them occurred within established relationships.... some which have lasted  **years.**

Even if we take it that he started from his *very* early university days, at which he was...let's say 18, if not 19, 20.... *Chronologically,* Peter has had some *lengthy* relationships, which (even in-story) took a *lot* of time... time in which *he,* and the girl in question, would be *aging.*  The **three most significant** ----- or at least, most *notable,* because of their length/duration, if not impact on him personally---- would likely be **Gwen Stacy, Felicia Hardy**/The Black Cat, and **Mary Jane Watson-Parker.**:

[image]

- **Gwen** as stated, was his college Sweetheart, and first big love. In "comic time," they were seeing each other (by most accounts) for more than 2 years, almost 3, give or take some drama (she left for Paris for about 6 months at one point); if they started at 18 or 19, that puts him at (youngest) 21 ( *maybe* 20) when she dies. Not only is the time itself a factor, but how this effects Peter's *future* relationships will be quite significant also. According to the comics, Peter didn't really get "*Serious*-serious" with another girl for some time; he was somewhat afraid that what had happened to Gwen (due to him being Spider Man) would happen again... not to mention that he *mourned her* for quite a while. How much time *precisely* passed in the comics has never been pinpointed. What is known is that at some point, he began "dating casually" before *truly* picking up with his next major lover...
- Although Mary Jane was *around*  during his time with Gwen (they dated on and off), Peter didn't become *intimately* involved with MJ until sometime later. In truth, neither were ready for more after the shock of Gwen's death.
  As such, it would be Felicia Hardy/ **Black Cat** who became is main lady mainstay at this point; their relationship was passionate, intense, volatile, hot, and carried over into their civilian personas. Outside comicbook time, the Black Cat was first introduced as an "ambiguous villian" character in the late 1970s. She became a romantic fixture in Spidey's life in the 80s, wanting to fight crime by Peter's side and turn over a new leaf from being a cat burglar to become more of a "sometimes heroine/anti-hero". This change of heart was thanks to Peter's inspiration; he was the first truly "good" man she felt she could totally trust.

Peter first realized he had feelings for Black Cat when she almost died trying to protect him in 1979; "Cat" as he affectionately calls her, remained an "On Again/Off Again" love interest even after Peter got his black symbiote costume in the midst of the *Secret Wars,* which happened in 1985. By most accounts of comic time, they were purportedly on this romantic rollercoaster for a year or more; keep in mind, this was after Gwen's death, so they *didn't* get together immediately. Even if we low ball it and say this happened.... let's be generous and say 6-18 months after Gwen's death, to give Peter a fair mourning period (which his sensitive nature would likely take), and accounting for the 5.5 year "real time" difference in Gwen's death up to then... Peter would *still* be 22-23 at his youngest when they finally broke up.

- **Mary Jane Watson** is often recognized as Peter's "End game True Love," having helped him heal somewhat from the loss of their mutual friend//his long time girlfriend, Gwen. Chronologically, in "real time", that death happened a decade or more before in the 1970s; they began dating again a "bit later" in the comics (actually 5-10 years, real time) and became serious *after* Peter came back from the *Secret Wars.* Their relationship had a LOT of ups and downs, from miscommunications, to emotional showdowns to near break ups and different big life events which took them away from each other....however, Peter would end up proposing.

### Adulting and Marriage years

Although they feared they were "marrying too young", indicating they were not *too long* out of university and likely still in the "early" 20s, Pete and MJ would officially tie the knot in 1987 in *The Amazing Spiderman Annual* #21. They remained happily married--- if with problems and a few notable "Super hero life stresses"---- up until the *much* maligned  *One More Day* story arch, where they essentially traded their "love" (all their years of marriage, *not* the shared emotional bond) to the demon Mephisto to save Aunt May's life in 2007. Given that Cat had moved to Paris by 1985/86 to start a new life, and Peter and MJ didn't "jump" into marriage but were still young, they were each likely around 24 years old... *probably* closer to 25. And by that time, they had been friends for almost 10 years, having met *just* before Peter entered university, or in his senior year in highschool, via Aunt May.

[image]

It is nearly *impossible* to determine how many "comic years" the Parkers were married for with **any** kind of certainty... but a safe estimation, given the *amount* of events they went through in their marriage, just personal and professional, would be "more than 5, but *less* than 10". So, if we average it out to maybe 5.5 years married (low ball), and presume they were both 23-24 ( again, *low* ball) when they jumped the broom, then as of *One More Day,* they were both around 28 or 29....more than likely, closer to 30.

[image]

Even if we eliminate *all* the other romantic drama in young Mr Parker's life, these three relationships *by themselves* would put Peter from 19 to *almost* 30! That's 10 years of adult drama spread over a roughly 42 year "real time" period from the time he started dating Gwen, til his divorce from Mary Jane(1965-2007)...and we haven't even *gotten* to his **current** iteration, yet!

The whole reason *One More Day* was instituted was that Marvel wanted to inject a sense of "freshness" into the Spiderman titles, and they thought the best way to do that was by making him an "unencumbered bachelor" again. As stated before, mature relationships can age a character, and adding "Adult themed romantic issues" on a character gives them a *completely* different feel and age to "Teen romance". This is the reason there's a difference in feel and portrayal between the *adult* 616 Peter and Mary Jane's relationship...

[image]

[image]

[image]

...and the "Teen butterflies" romance of *Spiderman Loves Mary Jane* and other teenage incarnations like *Ultimate Spiderman* (both the cartoon, and the admittedly darker comics).
[image]

Moving on, both figuratively and chronologically, from Peter's most definitive romance, we then come to the *Superior Spider-Man* stage. This was when Doctor Octopus' mind was inhabiting Peter's body, and ran from 2013-2014. It should be noted, however, that (canonically) a full year **Did NOT** pass in the comics at this point during Otto's time as Peter.

While essentially wearing his body and suppressing his consciousness, Otto Octavius does , in truth, an admirable job organizing Peter's life, to a degree; he finishes Peter's doctorate, starts *Parker Industries,* discovers ways to maximizes Peter's fighting potential, and even manages to put a dent in city crime. While doing all this, Peter/Doc Oc also starts a rather sweet, adult romance with a lovely woman called Anna Maria Marconi....

[image]

This was no "fly by night" dalliance or "interesting diversion", either; it seems Otto (in Peter's body) had *genuine feelings* for this woman! So much so that they had even *moved in together.* To my knowledge, he didn't really reveal his identity (as Dr. Octopus, not Spider Man) to her. Naturally, when Peter got his body back, this made things a *bit* difficult, especially since the man Anna Maria loved and had been living with was essentially "not the same person" anymore....

This created *further* complication (and *no end* of *hilarity*) when a young woman empowered by the exact same spider that bit Peter, **Cindy Moon, a.k.a. Silk,** became something of a fixture in Peter's life. This was not only because Silk is implied to be *another* significant relationship for Peter, but because of their shared biological and "Spider-Totem" origin.

Essentially, on a physical and *metaphysical* level, Peter and Cindy are very much "made for" or "keyed to" each other. One of the effects of this is that they consistently give off natural pheromones that **incessantly drives them to RAVENOUSLY MATE with one another, *regardless* of time, place OR other people involved!** This damn-near instinctual "Can't Fight it Spider Sex animal impetus" is unconscious and occurs if they are within 20 feet of one another, so.... well, stuff like THIS happens:

[image]

Even if we are to assume *only* a year to 18 months has passed from *OMD* to the time of *Superior Spider Man,* that still puts Peter...at his  **youngest.**..... at between 29-31. And given *everything* that happened in between (*Spider Geddon, Into the Spider Verse, Dead No More, War of the Spider Men, 2015 Secret Wars, House of M, House of X,* the Atlantean Invasion of Wakanda, just to name a few)....  it's kind of *hard* to justify how "only a year" could have viably passed.

**Final Answer:** Given all this accumulated evidence, by *most* accounts, the "main" continuity Earth 616 Spider man/Peter Parker *should be* in his early 30s in comics. At the *very least* he is a young adult, not yet close to middle age, and--- given room for error here, and events happening a bit before--- an **extremely generous** "best guess" would place him in his **very late 20s** if we are being *extra* conservative. As to why he doesn't age, or at the least seems to do so *extremely slowly* .... we put that down to the comic books sliding time line.

Again, this is just an educated estimation, and the comics themselves *could* prove otherwise, but until Marvel gives some official details, this is the best we can run with based around available evidence and supposition.

Comment: This answer really needs a bit more detail to flesh it out.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite....Boy! **Lobs a web ball at Paulie**. Yuh too _wutless!_    On a real, though, is what I'm postulating here farfetched, or fair?

Answer (score -1):

**Simple Answer:** As a comic character, traditionally, Spider Man doesn't "age" according to *our* chronological time. That being said, Peter Parker's relative "age" is going to depend **heavily**_ on the *version* (and to a lesser extent, type of media) we are talking about that is portraying the hero.

However, if its an "origin" story, whatever the media, they *always* start with Peter as a teen, *latest* as a very young adult. This is because his origin *has* to have him on either a school trip, or having access as a "student" to a lab; that's how he acquires his abilities.

The oldest version we get for this "origins" tale, to my knowledge, is the 1970s *The Amazing Spider-man*  live action TV show, starring Nicholas Hammond; Peter was a 20-something at the time:

In this show, Peter was a 20-something college student as opposed to High School kid, and got his powers *working* in the lab, as opposed to at a cutting edge science demonstration.

The little known *Spiderman* cartoon show of 1981....and its more popular, if more questionable in quality variant, *Spider-man & his Amazing Friends,* made Peter around the same age, but **definitely** in college. Safe to say he was about 20 or so here, but still a student.

Even the (arguably) **most popular** TV version of Spider Man, the 1990s *Spider Man:The animated series,* focused on Peter as an early 20s  (21-23) year old college student at Empire State University who had gotten his powers way back prior to the series start in high school.

To be fair, Peter was *also* said to be in his first years or so of college in the 1960s cartoon show, but people-----mostly J. Jonah Jameson---- often referred to him as a "young man" or a "teenager", so he was likely 18 or 19, at his youngest, *no more* than 20 at his oldest:

The 2000s CGI show, loosely based on the Sam Raimi first film, put Peter in roughly the same age; out of high school, and just in University, but post all the movie's events. So he was likely around 19-20:

For some reason, as the character's popularity resurged in the 2000s, *keeping him* in high school seemed to become the standard. My best guess is this was done to have him be more "identifiable" as a "kid" to Cartoon watching audiences, which is partly why he was created as a teen in the first place. This was capitalized on all throughout the 2010s, first with *Spectacular Spiderman*...

Here, Peter is 15/16 years old, relatively new to his powers and in Highschool.

Then *Disney* got a hold of him, and well... you **know** the House of Mouse was **not** gonna make a "more mature" character for their 8-12 core and 13-16 secondary audiences to keep following if they could milk that whole "He's just like me!" appeal out of it. This resulted in (my opinion) two of the *worst* cartoon iterations of the character, *Ultimate Spider-Man* ...

[image]

and the currently ongoing *Disney's Marvel Spider-Man* ....

[image]

Both of these versions put Peter Parker *squarely* in is middle teens (16 for *Ultimate,* 14 for *Marvel's*) , veering onto late teens at his *oldest* as the story progresses.

Now, not only do these newer versions *lack* a kick ass theme song, but they kind of "pander" to the "kiddy" audience with pop culture references and over the top silly comedy; I swear, MSM has a full episode showing (not titled, but themed) "What I/Spiderman did for my summer vacation", and yes, its as ridiculous as it sounds.

To be fair,  this has to do with the whole "origin story" aspect mentioned earlier, as well as with the media (cartoons) its being made for. Also to be fair, Disney probably wants the character to be identifiable with his current movie interaction (that being 2017's *Spiderman: Homecoming* and 2019 *Spiderman:Far from Home* ). These films protagonist is played by Tom Holland, a 21 year old actor who actually *was* a teenager when he first played Peter Parker back in *Avengers: Civil War*:

[image]

Also being fair, Spider-Man was originally made to be a sort of "comic reader proxy" back in the 1960s; instead of the heroes being adults with a kid/teen sidekick, a teenage/young adult kid *was* the hero. This meant he was more relatable, as he had every day problems, like money, school, crushes, and curfews, which readers could identify with.

This effect was kind of lost a bit as Peter in the *Comic books* aged.

A few articles have been written examining the phenomenon:
https://screenrant.com/reasons-teenage-peter-parker-better-than-adult-worse-homecoming/

In truth though, the Spider Man **we know** as *Main continuity* is FAR older than a teenager....Surprisingly enough, we'll examine the evidence of this Spider man's "likely true age" not through comic history....but examining his relationships with *other* comic book characters.

[image]

This answer is going to run a bit long, so I'll end this part *here* and provide the other as a separate examination, as it covers other aspects outside of "other media" and sticks  **exclusively** to comic books.